# Logging over multiple modules

Tags: python, logging, bottle

How can I log everything using Python 'logging' to 1 text file, over multiple modules?

**Main.py**:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='localhost - - [%(asctime)s] %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)
log_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('debug.out', maxBytes=2048576)


log = logging.getLogger('logger')
log.addHandler(log_handler)

import test
```

**Test.py**:

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('logger')
log.error('test')
```

debug.out stays empty. I'm not sure what to try next, even after reading the logging documentation.

**Edit**: Fixed with the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the correct logging level (at least ERROR if you want to get all messages with level ERROR or higher) and add a handler to write all messages into a file. For more details have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html.

Comment: Your code is wrong. Use `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in Test.py. And in Main.py you have to configure the logging object you got with `log = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. Also add your handlers to this logging object. Then use `log.error(msg)` and `log.debug(msg)`. Just follow the example in the section `Using logging in multiple modules` in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html.